# Using break in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I break a list comprehension based on a condition, for instance when the number `412` is found?

Code:

```
numbers = [951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
           615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
           386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 399,
           162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 815, 67,
           104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 958, 609, 842,
           451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470, 743, 527]

even = [n for n in numbers if 0 == n % 2]
```

So functionally, it would be something you can infer this is supposed to do:

```
even = [n for n in numbers if 0 == n % 2 and break if n == 412]
```

I *really* prefer:

- a one-liner
- no other fancy libraries like itertools, "pure python" if possible (read: the solution should not use any `import` statement or similar)

Comment: `itertools` is pure python.

Comment: Both conditions can't be fulfilled at the same time.

Comment: ... `itertools` is Python ... Overall this sounds like a job for a normal `for` loop.

Comment: Why the restriction on imports?

Comment: @Marcin Good question! Because I wanted python to show off its powers.

Comment: @Flavius:  Why is importing something from Python's own library not "showing off its powers"?

Comment: Because they'd argue about "the standard library, and not the language itself" blah blah.

Comment: @Flavius: *"they'd argue [...]"* is this homework?

Comment: No, it's not. "they" are some collegues I was trying to convince. Why always see the bad in people? Huh!

Comment: @Flavius:  So you are trying to convince your colleagues that you can write something hackish and ugly in Python and that will somehow impress them?

Comment: Nope, that python is more powerful than they think.

Comment: @Flavius: There's nothing evil or bad if it would have been homework, just a tag to let people now what it is, and why it may have such "strange" requirements.

Comment: @Flavius, much of the power of Python lies in its standard libraries. Would Python be "more powerful" if more of the standard library functions were built-ins instead? I think not. They're standard either way, but there would be more potential for namespace collisions if they were built-ins. Better to segregate them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
even = [n for n in numbers[:None if 412 not in numbers else numbers.index(412)] if not n % 2]
```

Just took F.J.'s code above and added a ternary to check if 412 is in the list. Still a 'one liner' and will work even if 412 is not in the list.

Comment: If 412 is not in `numbers` the last element is lost if it's even.

Comment: Who is F.J. and where is the "code above"? Do not mistake Stack Overflow for a (conventional) *forum*; per the [tour], answers may rise to the top or fall to the bottom.

Comment: @usr2564301. I will keep that in mind. When I answered this question **6 years ago** there must have been another answer that was rated above this that I improved on.

Comment: Do you still remember which answer you amended to? :)

Comment: @usr2564301 I think it should be this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572876/4458173

Comment: Thank you to all who contributed to sharing advice on this post. However, this is the kind of practice that just frustrates less-skilled people trying to make sense of this 12 months later. Can we avoid "one-liners" which result in "one-hour" trying to decode them?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez  No.  If you want to avoid them due to style/readability and effort that's perfectly fine - but some of us like to see what's possible and different way to do things.

Answer (score 76):

Use a function to raise `StopIteration` and `list` to catch it:

```
>>> def end_of_loop():
...     raise StopIteration
... 
>>> even = list(end_of_loop() if n == 412 else n for n in numbers if 0 == n % 2)
>>> print(even)
[402, 984, 360, 408, 980, 544, 390, 984, 592, 236, 942, 386, 462, 418, 344, 236, 566, 978, 328, 162, 758, 918]
```

For those complaining it is not a one-liner:

```
even = list(next(iter(())) if n == 412 else n for n in numbers if 0 == n % 2)
```

For those complaining it is hackish and should not be used in production code: Well, you're right. **Definitely.**

Comment: This is not list comprehension, from my understanding, BUT it's an one-liner (I'll consider it as such, since the function is only used because of an unexplicable limitation in python for those `raise` statements there), and it doesn't seem to have any drawbacks. +1ed

Comment: +0.  Clever.  But hackish and not a one-liner.

Comment: Is there a fix that is kosher in Python 3+?

Comment: @Zuza A very similar example is included in the PEP's ["Examples of breakage"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/#examples-of-breakage) section. You can find it at the end. A single line workaround will no longer be possible - you'll need to define a generator function.

Comment: `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration`

Answer (score 68):

You can use generator expressions together with [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
even_numbers = (n for n in numbers if not n % 2)
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 412, even_numbers))
```

**Edit**: I just noticed the requirement not to use any `import`s.  Well, I leave this answer here anyway.

Comment: And if he really wants his one liner: `[n for n in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 412, numbers) if not n % 2]`

Answer (score 28):

I know this is a VERY OLD post, however since OP asked about using `break` inside a `list-comprehension` and I was also looking for something similar, I thought I would post my findings here for future reference.

While investigating `break`, I came across little known feature of `iter` as `iter(callable, sentinel)` which return an iterator that **"breaks"** iteration once callable `function` value is equal to `sentinel` value.

```
>>> help(iter)
Help on built-in function iter in module __builtin__:

iter(...)
    iter(collection) -> iterator
    iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator

    Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
    supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
    In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.
```

Tricky part here is defining a function that would fit given problem. In this case first we need to convert given `list` of `numbers` to an `iterator` using `x = iter(numbers)` which feeds  as external variable into `lambda` function.

Next, our callable function is just a call to the iterator to spit out next value. The iterator then compares with our sentinel value (412 in this case) and "breaks" once that value is reached.

```
print [i for i in iter(lambda x=iter(numbers): next(x),412) if i %2 == 0]

>>> 
[402, 984, 360, 408, 980, 544, 390, 984, 592, 236, 942, 386, 462, 418,  
 344, 236, 566, 978, 328, 162, 758, 918]
```

Comment: Can you have it stop _after_ hitting value, rather than before?

Comment: I do not believe so. This arrangement by definition "breaks" iteration once callable function value is equal to sentinel value. You may want to look at @
WolframH solution and modify function to suite your needs.

Comment: A modification that avoids lambda and makes it shorter is to use `__next__`: `[i for i in iter(iter(numbers).__next__, 412) if i%2 == 0]`. However, though it is not clear, the original question implies that only the evens are checked against sentinel, so we can make this simpler: `list(iter((i for i in numbers if i%2 == 0).__next__, 412))`.

Answer (score 15):

If 412 will definitely be in the list you could use this:

```
even = [n for n in numbers[:numbers.index(412)] if not n % 2]
```

If you want to include 412 in the result just use `numbers[:numbers.index(412)+1]` for the slice.

Note that because of the slice this will be less efficient (at least memory-wise) than an itertools or for loop solution.

Comment: Not only because of the slice it is less efficient, it also has to make a linear search over the list.

Comment: @FelixKling - Nevertheless, in a quick timeit test with the other answers shows that this is faster for the sample data provided.  I would definitely expect the others to pass it as the data set increases though.

Comment: @FelixKling: The linear search for 412 is super-fast C code, while the other solutions test for 412 in Python code, some solutions calling a function (which is expensive in CPython) for *every number*. I'm sure this solution is faster! -- The list copy is also done in very fast C code; unless you are tight on memory there shouldn't be a performance problem. (OK, if the first number is 412 and the list has 10**6 entries, it's bad; but if 412 is the last number this solution should still be very, very fast.)

Comment: Considering the previous comment, +1ed.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for list displays (including list comprehensions) is here: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays

As you can see, there is no special `while` or `until` syntax. The closest you can get is:

```
even_numbers = (n for n in numbers if 0 == n % 2)
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 412, even_numbers))
```

(Code taken from Sven Marnach's answer, posted while I was typing this).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume it's because you took the code from someone else. At least you admitted it. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Once I met a similar question on SO, the answer was:

```
next((x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4] if x % 2 == 0), [])
```

The last `[]` needs as default to prevent the `StopIteration` error if not found

or

```
any(print(x) if x < 2 else True for x in range(5))
```

`print` to prove, he returns `None` (logically `False`).

Answer (score 0):

another sneaky one-line solution to solve `breaking in list comprehension`, with the help of `end` condition.

without using `numbers.index(412)`, maybe a little bit faster?

```
even = [n for end in [[]] for n in numbers
        if (False if end or n != 412 else end.append(42))
        or not end and not n % 2]
```

---

> ## Note: This is a bad idea. <sup><sub><sub>just for fun : )</sub></sub></sup>

as @WolframH said:

> For those complaining it is hackish and should not be used in production code: Well, you're right. **Definitely.**

Comment: This is interesting. Can you explain it what happens here?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the generator solution is outdated I came up with the following:

```
even = [n for n in next((numbers[:i] for i, n in enumerate(numbers) if n == 412)) if not n % 2]
```

Then I went back and saw Andrew Clark's answer which is the same but much better

```
even = [n for n in numbers[:numbers.index(412)] if not n % 2]
```

Regardless the best part about the slicing solution is you can choose to include or exclude a number of elements on either side of the ending element for example to get 412 and the number after:

```
even = [n for n in numbers[:numbers.index(412)+2] if not n % 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same very problem to **breaking the list comprehension**. And as many says, the highest voted solution is outdated since Python 3.5 for [PEP 479](https://peps.python.org/pep-0479/): A `StopIteration` thrown from inside of a generator will be cast into an `RuntimeError`, instead of ending the generator itself.

I'm currently in **Python 3.11.4**, and all other solutions (list slicing, `itertools.takewhile`, short-circuiting `any`, the breaker `iter`, and the `end` thing by @recnac) still works.

I find `takewhile` the most elegant and pythonic, however somehow I want to write some cursed one-liner, that actually breaks out of the list instead of skipping through the rest of the list, but that seems to be unfulfillable.