# Python List Comprehension. Generating a List by repeatedly calling a function till it returns a predefined value

Tags: python, function, return-value, list-comprehension

I would like to generate a list by repeatedly calling a function till the function return a predefined value.

```
myList = [i,r = foo() while i==0]

myList = [r1, r2, r3, r4...] as long as returned i value is == 0
```

Is there a way to do this using list comprehension?

Comment: Is a list comprehension truly a requirement?  Seems like this would be very easily written and read as a generator, for example.

Comment: Where are you getting the `r` values from? Does your function return two values?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/break-list-comprehension

Comment: Generator is also fine. The function foo() returns two values. i,r.

Comment: Is `foo` a generator function?

Comment: foo is not a generator function. It returns two different values when ever we call it i.e. i,r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def stop_iteration():
    raise StopIteration
```

If `foo()` is a generator:

```
myList = list((i,r) if i != 0 else stop_iteration() for (i,r) in foo())
```

else:

```
def foo_generator():
    i,r = foo()
    while i != 0:
      yield i,r
      i,r = foo()

myList = list(foo_generator())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a one-liner for that. However, by defining a simple generator which would wrap any given `foo`-like function, you can do it.

```
TEST = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0)]


def foo():
    return TEST.pop(0)


def foo_wrapper(foo_like):
    r, i = foo_like()
    while i == 0:
        yield r
        r, i = foo_like()


print list(foo_wrapper(foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that.  The only keywords that list comprehensions support are `for`, `if`, and `else` (and `lambda` of course).

So, you have to do a multi-line solution.  However there is no need to define a wrapper function.  This will work fine:

```
mylist = []
while True:   
    i, r = foo()
    if i: break
    mylist.append(r)
```

In the end, `mylist` will have everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended, but...

```
>>> def notyet(predicate):
        if predicate:
            raise StopIteration
        return True

>>> # note that below we're wrapping a generator expression in a 
>>> # call to `list` so that when `StopIteration` is raised your
>>> # program won't terminate.
>>> xs = list((i, r) for (i, r) in foo() if notyet(i!=0))
>>> # if we try this instead, your program will hit the buffers
>>> # when the predicate is satisfied.
>>> xs = [(i, r) for (i, r) in foo() if notyet(i!=0)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    xs = [(i, r) for (i, r) in foo() if notyet(i!=0)]
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 3, in notyet
raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```

It's much better to use itertools.takewhile in this situation.

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> xs = list(takewhile(lambda (i, r): i!=0, foo()))
```