# Convert measurement from String to Int or Float

Tags: python, string, int, measurement

I have the string

```
var = '7 msecs'
#var = int(var)
#var = float(var)
```

And I want to convert that to an integer (7), or float (7.0).
This conversion works in javascript, as it seems to take the first value before the following, non-numerical values.

How can I do this in Python?

I want a good way to do this, without having to do

```
var = int(var.split(' ')[0])
```

It should also work for:

```
'10mm' or '10.55€'
```

Considered duplicate ([Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string))

This question is different, as I'm trying to replicate the ability of parseInt/parseFloat in javascript which only returns the numbers at the beginning of a string. This other question is looking for all numbers in a string.

```
#What I want:
'123mm' -> 123
'123mm1' -> 123
```

Comment: the measurement is always in 'msecs'?

Comment: `int(var.split()[0])`

Comment: @Trimax well, no, its just msecs in my example as it's what I'm working with at the moment

Comment: Using RegEx is a way but isn't more pythonic; you must import the regex library.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yeah, I have considered that, but I was trying to avoid it because it doesn't look very pythonic

Comment: I think using `split` is quite pythonic, you don't need the white space, just empty parentheses splits on all white space and newlines

Comment: are the digits always going to be first in the string?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah, in this case, because its trying to extract the number from the start of a measurement. It could also be used for currency if you keep the symbol at the end of the string

Comment: @Chris_Rands how could you use it if there is no space, '10mm', or '10.55€'

Comment: provide 2-3 examples

Comment: you can get the float by using the regex pattern `^(\d+(\.\d+)?)`, then you get int() if you need.

Comment: If you can have  or integers or floats then you might be best off using a regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Extract numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: @Kristof in a way, but with this i'm trying to not use regex.

Comment: @Islarf The answers to that question contain other techniques than just RE.

Comment: @Kristof It's not an exact duplicate. as in this, I'm trying to duplicate the ability of parseInt(str) in Javascript.

If I had the string ('123msecs2') I don't want the 2 at the end back. the Javascript parseInt, will just return 123.   This other question wants to reap all numbers in a string. I'm trying to get only the numbers at the BEGINNING of a string. parseInt will return NaN on ('hi123hi')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have white space, use `split`:

```
>>> s = "123 msecs2"
>>> int(s.split()[0])
123
```

If you want to take the numbers from the start of a string only without white space (or using regex), try this:

```
>>> s = "123msecs2"
>>> int("".join(list(next(iter(())) if not x.isdigit() else x for x in s)))
123
```

Note, it takes inspiration from the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/break-list-comprehension) about breaking out of list comprehensions.

Comment: If you add the original (val.split()[0]), including this I'll accept the answer

Answer (score -1):

If   `var = '7 msecs'`

By **filter**:

```
int(filter(str.isdigit, var))
```

By **Regex**:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\d')
re.search(p, var)
```

Or By **join**:

```
s = ''.join(x for x in var if x.isdigit())
print int(s)
7
```

Answer (score -1):

This is already answered here: [Python: Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

You could use a regular expression to extract all numbers from a string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "7 msecs"
>>> re.findall(r"\d+", s)
["7"]
```

If you only want the first number from the string as int, you could use:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "7 msecs"
>>> int(re.findall(r"\d+", s)[0])
7
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid importing regex, you can try using [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit). But for what it's worth, I'd prefer `int(var.split()[0])` to this:

```
var = '7 msecs'
numeric_end = 0
for i in xrange(len(var)):
    if not var[i].isdigit():
        numeric_end = i
        break

print int(var[:numeric_end])
```

I chose to track the index of the first non-digit character instead of building a string for slight memory/performance reasons. This also only extracts the first number in the string.

This will of course, only work for ints. For a float, you would have to also accept the `.` character (and probably keep track of whether or not you already have to determine if it's a valid float string).