# convert double for loop with lambda function and break to list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I've following code that I need to convert to `list-comprehension` (one liner). However, I am unable to do so.
The code calculates prime numbers up-to input range of  `A`.

```
def sieve(A):    
    l = []
    f = lambda x : int(x**0.5)
    for p in range(2,A+1):        
        for i in range(2, f(p) + 1):
            if p % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            l.append(p)
    return l
```

So far I've following which does not work. Especially the `break` within `for-loop` is throwing me off.

```
list(set([val for sublist in [[p  for i in range(2, f(p) + 1) if p %i != 0 ] for p in range(2,A) ] for val in sublist]))
```

**EDIT**
Adding constraints for the problem.
The code can only be one statement, without `eval` or `exec`. The code must be at most 160 character long.

Comment: Why? I pity the person who has to try and decipher this list comprehension.

Comment: Why in the first place do you want it to be converted to list comprehension?

Comment: I know, It's part of a online problem that accepts only one liner solution. Unless there is some other way to provide one liners.

Comment: Regarding adding a break condition to a list comprehension - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/break-list-comprehension

Comment: I mean, not recommended but there is always the [Oneliner-izer](http://onelinepy.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Thanks @ bunji, I tried , but the one liner is really long.  I need it under 160 ch, so I am assuming I will need different approach.

Comment: Concatenate your py file with `\n`'s and then use exec on the resulting string. This will work for any file

Comment: I added constraints to the problem. Can't use `eval` or `exec`. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[p for p in range(2,A+1) if next((i for i in range(2, int(p**0.5) + 1) if (p % i) == 0),None)==None]
```

Code is 100 chars long.
We use [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to break out of the iteration.
**Explanation**

```
def sieve(A):
  [p for p in range(2,A+1) if getFirstDiv(p)==None]

def getFirstDiv(p):
  next(divIter(p),None)

def divIter(p):
  return (i for i in range(2, int(p**0.5) + 1) if (p % i) == 0)
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
15 --> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
10 --> [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Ah, so I was missing out on next(), good to know. It works perfectly even for A=10000+ within given time constraints. thx.

Answer (score 1):

This one liner will do it:

```
[r for r in [i*all([i if i%j!=0 else 0 for j in range(2,i)]) for i in range(2,x)] if r>0]
```

You just need to set `x` (the maximum value).

Note: it is not particularly efficient, although I'm guessing efficiency isn't the aim of this question.

Explanation (expanded code):

```
filtered = []
primes = []

for i in range(2,x):
    # Check that all numbers up to i do not divide i
    # I realise we only need to check up to int(sqrt(i))
    condition = all([i if i%j!=0 else 0 for j in range(2,i)])

    # Exploit Python's treatment of bool: number*True = number and number*False=0
    filtered.append( i*condition )


for r in filtered:
    # Take out all the zeros
    if r>0:
        primes.append(r)
```