# Using break or continue in [] in python gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, break, continue

I would like to use one line to finish the for loop

But some thing wrong happen...

When I use the statement continue or break it gives the error

I create some easy code as a example:

```
l=[]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if i==j:
            l.append(i+j)
        else:
            break
```

which the result would be

```
[0]
```

If I try to do it in one line,Here's my try:

```
list_= [i+j if i==j else break for i in range(3) for j in range(3) ]
```

And the error is raised: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
list_= [i+j if i==j else break for i in range(3) for j in range(3) ]
                               ^
```

Which I actually don't know how to fix it...

Can Somebody help me out? Thanks

Comment: You cannot `break` out of a list comprehension, see for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/break-list-comprehension).

Comment: You cannot use any keywords which are not also values in place of an expression