# Is there a way to have python start a the match statement when a string is found so that loop doesn't start from the beginning?

Tags: python, python-3.x

File includes:

```
Honda
color white
trim black
Chevy
color blue
trim chrome
Hyundai
color red
trim black
```

Let's say I have hypothetical data from above. I'm trying to create a loop so that when Hyundai is found I get color red.  The problem I'm having is when Hyundai is found the loop starts again from the beginning and I get white.

```
for line in data:
    if Hyundai in line:
       for line in data:
           if 'color' in line:
               color = get_color(line)
               print (color)
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: How far ahead after you find hyundai do you want to look for color? 1 line? 2 lines? until the end of the data?

Comment: Thank you khelwood for formatting correctly.  I was trying to that figure it out.

Comment: SyntaxVoid,  I want to exit the loop when the color is found.

Comment: I had a similar problem.
Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316679/pythonic-way-of-processing-a-file-between-two-previously-known-strings&ved=2ahUKEwjCsMaD9YLkAhXKRxUIHcbyDawQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3vQ34nMVjlwZDAvU7jE8me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a function and return:

```py
def getCarColor(car, data):

    car_found = False

    for line in data:
        if car in line:
            car_found = True
        if 'color' in line and car_found:
            return get_color(line)

    return None

print(getCarColor("Hyundai", data))
```

Comment: I tried the function as you prescribed and I still get 'white' instead of 'red'.  I also put it in a loop and all the cars color is 'white'.  It seems like the second for loop starts from the beginning of the file and matching color white.

Comment: Should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

The loops starts again from the beginning because you went out of your way to tell it to do so.  Instead, you need a simple state machine.  In the "start state", you're looking for the specific model name.  Once that's found, you're in the "want color" state, in which you *continue* through the data to find the next line with "color".

```
model = "Hyundai"
state = 0

for line in data:
    if state == 0:   # Look for desired model:
        if model in line:
            state = 1
    elif state == 1:
        if "color" in line:
            color = get_color(line)
            break
```

This is detailed and dirty, but the concept works.  However, if you have to do this repeatedly then change your algorithm altogether.  Build a reference dict with the various models and their attributes.  You'll make *one* pass through the data; after that, all uses will be by direct look-up, *not* by re-parsing the input text.  You'll want to finish with something like:

```
look_up = [
    {"model": "Honda",
     "color": "white",
     "trim": "black"},
    {"model": "Chevy",
     "color": "blue",
     "trim": "chrome"},
    {"model": "Hyundai",
     "color": "red",
     "trim": "black"}
]
```

Doing so is a different question ... give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the recommendation.  When I get better with python I'll try that.