# Stop loop with list comprehension when find the first True

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, break

I want to stop the iteration when I find the first True, like this:

```
>> for x in ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3]:
>>    if isinstance(x, int):
>>        print(x)
>>        break

 1
```

How can I do the same thing but with **list comprehension** for-loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [break list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/break-list-comprehension)

Comment: While that is possible, it is going to be much less beautiful than a loop.

Comment: A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a succinct way of creating a `list`, not searching though one for something until it is found and then printing it out — which is what your code is doing. Please be more specific about what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `next` on a generator expression to return the first `True` instance:

```py
x = next((a for a in ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3] if isinstance(a, int)), None)
print(x)
1

x = next((a for a in ['a', 'b'] if isinstance(a, int)), None)
print(x)
None
```

Where the second argument is a return value that allows you to avoid `StopIteration` errors

### Edit (credit @martineau)

This can be reduced to the `filter` operator as shown by the itertools recipe above:

```py
x = next(filter(int.__instancecheck__, ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3]), None)
```

Comment: Your code could be shortened since a large portion of it is equivalent to what the built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function does — which is probably why the `itertools` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) named `first_true()` uses it.

Comment: True, a `next(filter(...))` would probably be faster here

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in mechanism for finding the first element of a list that matches a predicate. There is [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), which you can use to determine *if* such an element exists, but that won't tell you what element it was.

```
any(isinstance(x, int) for x in ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3])
```

Luckily, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) provides a variety of functions for when you want to do some operation on a list or any other iterable.

The function you're looking for isn't built in to the module, but the documentation provides definitions for a handful of functions, including this one, as the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). The function you need is named `first_true`. Just copy the definition, and:

```
def first_true(iterabe, default=False, pred=None):
    return next(filter(pred, iterable), default)

x = first_true(['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3], pred=int.__instancecheck__)
```

If nothing in the list matches the predicate, `first_true` will return `False`. If you want a different behavior, you can modify the function. The other recipes might be a good place to start if you want to understand how to work with iterators in the itertools style.

---

If you're trying to do more complicated processing in the loop than just finding the first matching element, you're probably better off using a proper `for` loop, though. List comprehensions and generator expressions are good as a replacement for map and filter, and itertools provides more general operations on iterables, but they aren't meant to stand in for real loop logic.

Comment: I'm getting `NameError: name 'first_true' is not defined`

Comment: You need to define the `first_true` function, using the definition in the list at the link. You'll need to import a few functions from `itertools` to do so. (I'd include the definition here, but I don't own the copyright to it.)

Comment: @jirassimok: Python is open source, so don't worry about copying code from it, especially from example its documentation (as long a you cite the source like you're doing).

Comment: @martineau I'm aware; it should fall under fair use. I'm not sure what else I was thinking of when I wrote that, actually.

Comment: Although defining a function according to the `itertools` recipe would more elegant and readable, it's so short one could simply use it — i.e. `x = next(filter(int.__instancecheck__, ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3]), None)`.

Comment: You do not "need to import a few functions from `itertools`" first — `next()` and `filter()` are built-ins.

Comment: @martineau Oh, duh. I don't think I actually looked at the definition when I wrote the answer. Updated.