# Use an else clause like the ones in formal for loops but in a list comprehension, is it possible?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

Here is an example of my initial list of lists:

```
trip_chains = [['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid'], 
               ['Delhi', 'London', 'New York'],
            ...['Jerusalem', 'Cairo', 'Paris']]
```

I want to extract another list out of **trip_chain**, to be like this:

```
chains_steps = [[['London', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Madrid'], ['Madrid', 'London']], 
                [['Delhi', 'London'], ['London', 'New York'], ['New York', 'Delhi']],
             ...[['Jerusalem', 'Cairo'], ['Cairo', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Jerusalem']]]
```

So I am using a list comprehension with two for loops in it:

```
chains_steps = [[chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1]] for chain_ in trip_chains for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_)-1)]
```

but because I'm loosing the step returning me to the starting city, the result will look like this:

```
chains_steps = [[['London', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Madrid']], 
                [['Delhi', 'London'], ['London', 'New York']],
             ...[['Jerusalem', 'Cairo'], ['Cairo', 'Paris']]]
```

Since we can think of this **list comprehension** as a double nested **for** loop,
and as we know that **for** loops come with an optional **else** clause:

```
chain_steps = []
for chain_ in trip_chains:
    for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_)-1):
        chain_steps.append([chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1])
    else:
        chain_steps.append([chain_[-1], chain_[0]])
```

I am wondering if I could use this **else** clause in the **list comprehension**  in this way:

```
    chains_steps = [[chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1]] for chain_ in trip_chains for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_)-1) else [chain_[-1], chain_[0]]]
```

I know there may be a bunch of alternative solution's for this specific problem, but I'm asking it for sake of curiosity and knowledge.

P.S. One may want to run a function just after every time the inner loop is finished. So this issue is not specific to my example.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Not really, I'm not talking about if else... thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. But why not just `chains_steps = [[chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1]] for chain_ in trip_chains for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_)-1)] + [chain_[-1], chain_[0]]`?

Comment: It also isn't really necessary to use the `else` clause of the `for` loop in your example, it only makes a difference if there is a `break` in the loop. In your case you could have just moved the statement from the `else` part to after the loop so that it is executed afterwards unconditionally.

Comment: Assume that I wanted to run a function, like print, or rechecking connection status to a server etc... right after every iteration of the outer for loop, inside the list comprehension.

Comment: `else` only makes sense  if the loop has a `break` statement somewhere in it; and `break` statements cannot be used in loop comprehensions. So the question seems to be based on a misunderstanding of what `for`/`else` actually does.

Comment: @kaya3 Sorry but disagree. Because this is a nested loop situation.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion; the only reason to ever have an `else` block after a `for` loop is if there is a `break` statement in the `for` loop, and list comprehensions cannot have `break` statements in them. Those are facts, and it has nothing to do with whether it is a nested loop or a nested list comprehension. As I said, your question seems to be based on a misunderstanding, and you thinking it matters that the loops are nested only confirms that.

Comment: Please make your answer more clear. There are two `for` loops, and when you say `for` loop I don't know which one do you mean! I want to have an operation triggered before every time the outer `for` loop goes into the next iteration, and this is only possible if in the inner for loop, an `else` clause be fitted.

Comment: It is worth noticing that your example using two explicit `for` statements does not produce your desired output! It produces a list of lists (starts with `[[`) whereas your desired output is a list of lists of lists (starts with `[[[`).

Comment: @Ture Pålsson I agree, to circumvent this, I'm using another list which contains element count of each of the lists, and use elementary math to index into the desired elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `for...else`

I recommend that you study the `for...else` semantic. The comment by @mkrieger1 is a maybe a bit concise.
The [doc states](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs.

For instance:

```
>>> for i in range(1):
...     print("first and only iteration")
...     break
... else: # not executed since there is a break
...     print("no break was met")
first and only iteration
```

But:

```
>>> for i in range(1):
...     print("first and only iteration")
... else: # executed since the loop exits normally
...     print("no break was met")
first and only iteration
no break was met
```

If no break ever happens in the body of the loop, the else clause always run,
and thus the following pieces of code are equivalent:

```
for ...:
    <loop body>
else:
    <else statement>
```

And:

```
for ...:
    <loop body>
<else statement>
```

## A list of lists of lists or a list of lists?

You write:

```
chain_steps = []
for chain_ in trip_chains:
    for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_)-1):
        chain_steps.append([chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1]])
    else:
        chain_steps.append([chain_[-1], chain_[0]])
```

As @Ture Pålsson write, thats only produces a list of lists. The correct version would be:

```
trip_chains = [['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid'],
               ['Delhi', 'London', 'New York'],
               ['Jerusalem', 'Cairo', 'Paris']]

chain_steps = []
for chain_ in trip_chains:
    chain_step = [] # create a new list in the outer loop
    # and fill it in the inner loop
    for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_)-1):
        chain_step.append([chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1]])
    chain_step.append([chain_[-1], chain_[0]])
    chain_steps.append(chain_step)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(chain_steps)
```

Output:

```
[[['London', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Madrid'], ['Madrid', 'London']],
 [['Delhi', 'London'], ['London', 'New York'], ['New York', 'Delhi']],
 [['Jerusalem', 'Cairo'], ['Cairo', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Jerusalem']]]
```

No "elementary math" is needed.

## Can we add an `else` clause in a list comprehension?

The main question is: can we have a `break` in a list comprehension? The answer is no (Python 3):

```
>>> [i if i<5 else break for i in range(10)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [i if i<5 else break for i in range(10)]
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(See [Using break in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/using-break-in-a-list-comprehension) for more details).

Hence, the `else` clause has **no meaning** in a list comprehension. Consequence: we cannot have an `else` clause in a list comprehension.

## Can we add an extra element in a list comprehension?

I will focus on the inner loop:

```
chain_ = ['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid']

chain_step = []
for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_)-1):
    chain_step.append([chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1]])
chain_step.append([chain_[-1], chain_[0]]) # extra element

pprint(chain_step)
```

Output:

```
[['London', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Madrid'], ['Madrid', 'London']]
```

Obviously, we can add an iteration with the last element:

```
chain_step = []
for stepscount_ in list(range(len(chain_)-1))+[-1]:
    chain_step.append([chain_[stepscount_], chain_[stepscount_+1]])
```

And then:

```
>>> chain_ = ['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid']
>>> [[chain_[s], chain_[s+1]] for s in list(range(len(chain_)-1))+[-1]]
[['London', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Madrid'], ['Madrid', 'London']]
```

That's a bit overkill when you can write:

```
>>> chain_ = ['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid']
>>> [[chain_[s], chain_[s+1]] for s in range(len(chain_)-1)] + [[chain_[-1], chain_[0]]]
[['London', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Madrid'], ['Madrid', 'London']]
```

(You can easily wrap this in an outer list comprehension:

```
chain_steps = [
    [[chain_[s], chain_[s+1]] for s in range(len(chain_)-1)] + [[chain_[-1], chain_[0]]]
    for chain_ in trip_chains
]
```

)

## Bonus: is there a cleaner way to write this?

**YES** (inner loop):

```
chain_step = []
for step in zip(chain_, chain_[1:]+[chain_[0]]):
    chain_step.append(step)

pprint(chain_step)
```

Output:

```
[('London', 'Paris'), ('Paris', 'Madrid'), ('Madrid', 'London')]
```

The `zip` function will pair the elements:

```
chain[0], chain[1], ... chain_[n-2], chain_[n-1]  <-  chain_
chain[1], chain[2], ... chain_[n-1], chain_[0]    <-  chain_[1:]+[chain_[0]]
```

As you see, you have a list of tuples, not a list of lists. That's better, because a step is a pair, not a list (a tuple size won't change, a list size might change).

Hence the final double list comprehension:

```
>>> trip_chains = [['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid'],
...                ['Delhi', 'London', 'New York'],
...                ['Jerusalem', 'Cairo', 'Paris']]
>>> [[step for step in zip(chain_, chain_[1:]+[chain_[0]])] for chain_ in trip_chains]
[[('London', 'Paris'), ('Paris', 'Madrid'), ('Madrid', 'London')], [('Delhi', 'London'), ('London', 'New York'), ('New York', 'Delhi')], [('Jerusalem', 'Cairo'), ('Cairo', 'Paris'), ('Paris', 'Jerusalem')]]
```

Or, because the inner list comprehension just takes the elements of `zip`:

```
>>> [list(zip(chain_, chain_[1:]+[chain_[0]])) for chain_ in trip_chains]
[[('London', 'Paris'), ('Paris', 'Madrid'), ('Madrid', 'London')], [('Delhi', 'London'), ('London', 'New York'), ('New York', 'Delhi')], [('Jerusalem', 'Cairo'), ('Cairo', 'Paris'), ('Paris', 'Jerusalem')]]
```

Beware: the code becomes hard to maintain...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have `else` branches on list comprehensions.

You could loop over `chain + [chain[0]]` or play tricks with the `%` operator to "fold" stepscount back to the beginning. Or just add the last pair manually, as @mkrieger suggests in a comment.

Comment: Yes I see. Currently I'm using some additional ternary operators inside the chain_ indexing operators: `chain_[stepcounts_ if stepcounts_<len(chain_) else -1]`. But it could really help to reduce code volume if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Another New Answer**

Based on the S.Khajeh'comment, I am adding another one-line solution, which is **more generic**  and **cover situation which has strokes with non-uniform unconfined stroke lengths**

*Modified to be more effecient than double comparison* :)

```
chains_steps = [[[row[i], (row + [row[0]])[i + 1]] for i in range(len(row))] for row in trip_chains]
```

*Before*

```
chains_steps = [[[(row + row)[i], (row + row)[i + 1]] for i in range(len(row))] for row in trip_chains]
```

**The old answer**

You can also achieve your target, by directly coding as in the following line:

```
chains_steps = [ [ [row[0],row[1]] , [row[1],row[2]] , [row[2],row[0]] ]  for row in trip_chains]
```

the output is

```
chains_steps
Out[7]: 
[[['London', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Madrid'], ['Madrid', 'London']],
 [['Delhi', 'London'], ['London', 'New York'], ['New York', 'Delhi']],
 [['Jerusalem', 'Cairo'], ['Cairo', 'Paris'], ['Paris', 'Jerusalem']]]
```

as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now please consider another situation which has strokes with non-uniform unconfined stroke lengths.

Comment: Yes this trick handles the situation. But a small draw back of it, IMO is, it is adding an extend operation to every iteration of the outer loop which may reduce the efficiency of the comprehension list.

Comment: Currently I am using this solution:

`chains_steps = [[chain_[stepscount_ if stepscount_<len(chain_)-1 else -1], chain_[stepscount_+1 if stepscount_<len(chain_)-1 else 0]] for chain_ in trip_chains for stepscount_ in range(len(chain_))]` which I believe is enough efficient, but what if I want to perform an operation every time the outer loop reiterates! The base idea is more general than this specific problem.

Comment: I added another modification, but in your final solution, `len()` is performed twice with two `if` statements and one addition, and all of them are repeated every iteration, so It is better to compare the different solutions based on time measurement. it will be a nice trip :} Thanks

Comment: I tried your three solutions on a larger list with 2598 elements. The first one being the fastest one took 0.002s, the second one took a bit more than 0.0045 on average, which is the time consumed by the solution I suggested. And the third one is a bit faster than my solution. All of your suggestions are satisfying for this problem. Except for the second one, in cases in which memory efficiency is a matter. Thank you.