# In Python, how can I use 'break' in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, break

Simple example would be to get prefix from two strings

```
s1 = "abcd666678"
s2 = "abcd777778"
```

Is it possible to get common prefix `abcd` using list comprehension. I am trying as below however I am getting `abcd78`, all common characters, how to break after `abcd`

```
"".join([s1[i] for i in range(min(len(s1), len(s2))) if s1[i]==s2[i]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using break in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/using-break-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 2):

There is a builtin function which does what you want: [os.path.commonprefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix)

```
>>> import os
>>> s1 = "abcd666678"
>>> s2 = "abcd777778"
>>> os.path.commonprefix([s1, s2])
'abcd'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.takewhile` and `zip`:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> ''.join(x for x, _ in takewhile(lambda t: t[0] == t[1], zip(s1, s2)))
'abcd'
```