# Is there a list comrehension "break" syntax?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've had a look through the "similar questions" section as well as searching the site, but unfortunately I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

**Unimportant preface:**

I'm working on a function that takes in `value` and `base` as integers and returns `value` rewritten in the specified base. eg `baseFunc(10,2)` will return `'1010'`

For readability, here's a copy that doesn't bother with latin characters

**Code:**

```
digits = [[value%base, value:=value//base][0] for _ in range(value) if value]
```

**Expectation Vs Outcome:**

I expected this syntax to enact a `break` on the loop when `value` reaches 0, however instead it iterates `value` number of times, and only appends an item if `value:=value//base` is yet to reduce `value` to 0.

This behavior seems quite obvious now that I know.

**What I Need For Expected Functionality:**

I would like to know how to enact `break` from inside a list comprehension based on some `if` statement, if it's even possible. I'm 100% okay with hacky alternatives as this project will never be in production.

Could I just use a for loop and the `.append()` built in? Absolutely, but I would still like to know.

**TL;DR:**

What list comprehension syntax would be equivalent to `if criteria: break`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using break in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/using-break-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: Maybe you can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=filterfalse#itertools.takewhile).

Comment: Short answer is genexpr + `itertools.takewhile` (which wraps which depends on whether the condition is based on the inputs or the outputs) that you `list`ify.

Comment: add condition with `if` to statement

Comment: @Vova That won't stop the iteration.

Comment: @Matthias of course, but list comprehension is for building iteration, not for searching data