# Stopping to build list from xls using xlrd when first empty row

Tags: python, list-comprehension, xlrd

I am creating a list based on an xls file. But I want to stop this when in encounter the first empty row. I tried:

```
    data = [[ws.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(ws.ncols)] for r in range(ws.nrows)]
```

Which create the list with all rows.

Then I tried:

```
    data = [[ws.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(ws.ncols)] if not cell.ctype in (xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY, xlrd.XL_CELL_BLANK) for r in range(ws.nrows)]
```

To have the empty rows removed but this gives me an error of invalid syntax.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The `if` statement go last, it should be `[[ws.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(ws.ncols)] for r in range(ws.nrows) if not cell.ctype in (xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY, xlrd.XL_CELL_BLANK)]`

Answer (score 1):

1. In list-comprehension, if you want to use if-statement, you need put it after for statement:

```
[f(x) for x in sequence if condition]
```

- In your code it should be:

```
[[ws.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(ws.ncols)] for r in range(ws.nrows) if not cell.ctype in (xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY, xlrd.XL_CELL_BLANK)]
```

2. Then, you need a break in a list-comprehension.You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572833/using-break-in-a-list-comprehension) to select a solution to do it.But I suggest to use simple for loop rather than list-comprehension in this case.