# Python convert "for > if > break" to one line

Tags: python

How I can convert this code to one line?

```
target = 3
res = None
for x, y in [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]:
    if x == target:
        res = y
        break
```

Surely I can use list comprehensive but it's doesn't have a `break` statement

I tried:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46610595/11277611) solution and a such code:

```
res = iter(lambda x=iter([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]): next(x), (1, 2))
next(res)  # StopIteration
```

But  both are failed

Comment: You should look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html. Or just not convert it to one line!

Comment: Your code mixes up `x` and `y` so I can't be sure what you meant, but it is something like `y_target = next((y for x, y in l if x == x_target), None)`. Please make sure you post [example] (with emphasis on being correct and reproducible) in the future.

Comment: This is probably clearer as a for loop anyway. I would extract the for loop into a function, then call that function from your other code. (That makes it a one-liner from your other code. ;)

Comment: Sorry for mixing, I missed this. Now the code is edited.

Comment: "Surely I can use list comprehensive" why would you want to? your code doesn't create a list, and is fine just like it is. List comprehensions do not have a break, they are for mapping/filtering operations

Comment: A oneliner, although doesn't break: `res = dict(reversed(pairs)).get(target)`

Comment: You can try solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364277/9166673