# Break on same line as for loop and if statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, break

I am trying to stop iterating through the for loop as soon as it comes across the number 5. Is there a way to add a break to this statement rather than just skip over the 5, in one line without importing anything?

```
(x for x in num if x != 5)
```

Comment: Would it be ok if you define your own function? Or are you looking for a pure list comprehension-based solution?

Comment: a pure list comprehension solution

Comment: Then based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46610595/15873043) you'd have to do something like `[i for i in iter(lambda x=iter(nums): next(x), 5)]` which I really don't recommend because it's so cryptic.

Comment: maybe `[x[1] for x in enumerate(nums) if x[0] < nums.index(5)]`?

Comment: @Sajad the number 5 is not guaranteed to be in the list so it's giving me a error sometimes

Comment: Simplest solution is to check that 5 exists: `...if 5 in nums and x[0] < nums.index(5)`

Answer (score 2):

Try [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```py
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x!=5, nums))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: is there another way to do it without importing anything, sorry I should have specified that

Comment: Probably there is, but I'd assume it's going to be obscure.