# Find the first occurrence of the specific attribute in list of dictionaries - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I have a similar dataset

```
dataset = [
    {
        'Country': 'GB',
        'Pollutant': 'SO2',
        'Pollution': 10
    },
    {
        'Country': 'AL',
        'Pollutant': 'O3',
        'Pollution': 10,
        'Year': 2015
    },
    {
        'Country': 'BE',
        'Pollutant': 'SO2',
        'Pollution': 5,
        'Year': 2016
    }
]
```

In this case, the first object doesn't have 'Year' attribute. I want to find the first occurrence of the year attribute and capture its value.
So I tried this:

```
[x for x in dataset if hasattr(x,'Year')][0]['Year']
```

This is giving index out of range error.

Later I tried this to find if the specific attribute is there :

```
for x in dataset:
    print(any('Year' in x for x in dataset))
```

But this is returning true of all the list objects.
Can someone guide me how to get the first 'Year' attribute value, preferably in single line code.

Comment: well, for your loop, you just want `print('Year' in x))` because `any('Year' in x for x in dataset)` checks every value in the dataset already.

Comment: "preferably in single line code." Why such a silly arbitrary constraint?

Comment: `hasattr` is the incorrect way to check if a *key is in a dict*. You wanted `[x for x in dataset if 'Year' in x]`... just like you did in your second example.

Comment: 1- get it to work with as many lines you need. 2- if your working code looks less concise than it could, iterate to make it more concise until happy. 3- one-liners just for the sake of it is rarely a good idea...

Comment: I don't get why anyone would think and recommend building an entire list just to finally keep the first element. What a potential waste of resource.

Comment: @Julien , Thanks for the recommendation. I'll work on it. And to answer your question- I get this data from database at high frequency and I need to get the value of the first occurrence of the Year attribute. But the entire dataset is also used for some other calculation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , Thanks for the answer. I see now what mistake I have done.

Comment: you might use `x.has_key('Year')`

Comment: @CrazyCoder the point is that using a list comprehension will iterate over the whole dataset, and potentially, builds a large list. It would make more sense to simply use a for-loop and `break` when you find the first value. This would 1) potentially iterate many less items 2) doesn't have to build any other list

Comment: @rioV8 there is no such method, and even when that method existed in Python 2, the idiomatic approach was to use `key in my_dict` instead of `my_dict.has_key(key)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `get()`. It will not give error if the object is not present. It will return `None`

```
dataset = [{'Country': 'GB', 'Pollutant': 'SO2', 'Pollution': 10},
 {'Country': 'AL', 'Pollutant': 'O3', 'Pollution': 10, 'Year': 2015},
 {'Country': 'BE', 'Pollutant': 'SO2', 'Pollution': 5, 'Year': 2016}]

result = [x.get("Year") for x in  dataset]
print(result)

#output
[None, 2015, 2016]
```

---

Since `'Year'` is not present in first dictionary. We will take index 1:

```
[x.get("Year") for x in  dataset][1]

#output
2015
```

[get()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right! In the first place I am giving them list comprehension with all the values. `None` shows that `Year` is missing from that particular dictionary, Once they have all the values they can take whatever they want from the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```py
[x for x in dataset if hasattr(x,'Year')][0]['Year']
```

<strike>`hasattr()` would return True or False, so `[0]` makes no sense, hence `index out of range`</strike>

Missed the closing bracket, while this would work if the dataset had class instances, you have a dictionary so you would need to change `hasattr` to `'Year' in x` (or `x.has_key('Year')` if you're in an old version of python), still if you had a dataset of 1,000,000 you would need to iterate all of the elements just to keep the first one, waste of time. It's better to loop and break on the first occurrence.

As for

```py
for x in dataset:
    print(any('Year' in x for x in dataset))
```

`any()` will return True if any of the iterable evaluates to true or False if all of them are False.
Also, you're iterating dataset twice, first in the main loop and then in the list comprehension.

You could do this

```py
for x in dataset:
    if 'Year' in x:
        break
```

That way, once x has 'Year' it won't continue with the reas and will stop the loop.

Edit:

Here's a previous answer that explains how to "break" in a list comprehension if you really, REALLY need to keep it to 1 line.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572933/5640517

But you really shouldn't since you said `preferably` I guess it's not a MUST.

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.
>
> *-Abelson & Sussman, Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*

Comment: it is not missing a closing bracket, and `[0]` *does* make sense, and it isn't really relevant what the predicate returns since it is indexing the list

Comment: True, missed it was between ) and [ so it's grabbing the first value of the list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for addressing the feedback, I think your for-loop is a good solution. Also note: "Also, you're iterating dataset twice" worse than that! You are iterating over the dataset `len(dataset)` times! IOW, you are doing something that is quadratic time totally unnecessarily!

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea, but `hasattr` checks if an object a specific attribute. In your case, the elements of the list are dictionaries, and you could use the `in` operator to check for a specific key's existence:

```py
result = [x for x in dataset if 'Year' in x][0]['Year']
```

Note that this will still fail with an `IndexError` if no dictionary in the list has a `Year` key. Instead of using the `0` index, a slightly more robust approach could be using `next`:

```py
result = next((x['Year'] for x in dataset if 'Year' in x), None)
```

Comment: I hesitate to call the `next(..., None)` approach more *robust*. Now your variable `result` can contain `None`, so you are just pushing a potential `AttributeError` or `TypeError` down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand good what you are looking for, that would work.

```
first_year_ocur = next((x['Year'] for x in dataset if 'Year' in x), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no `first` built-in in python, but it's easy to write:

```
from typing import Iterator


def first(it: Iterator):
    try:
        return next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

or simply:

```
def first(it: Iterator):
    return next(it, None)
```

Once you've got this, the rest is easy:

```
val = first(x['Year'] for x in dataset if 'Year' in x)
print(val) # 2015

val = first(x['Foobar'] for x in dataset if 'Foobar' in x)
print(val) # None
```

Comment: your `first` implementation can essentially (and somewhat idiomatically, but I don't personally like the approach) be replaced by `next(iterator, None)` But fundamentally, stop introducting `None`! It is *better* that an exception occur, *catch the exception and handle it*. don't kick the can down the road

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: right, forgot about the 2nd param

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that searches the list using a predicate.

It will stop searching at the first element that gives `True` as the predicate result.

```py
def iter_find_pred(itr, pred):
  for x in itr:
    if pred(x):
      return x
  return None

element = iter_find_pred(dataset, lambda x: 'Year' in x)
if element: element = element['Year']

print(element)
```